# Balance volume on both audio channels in a video file

Tags: video, audio, processing

I have a video file where one audio channel is much louder than the other.

Could I take the louder channel and mix it with the low channel? I know it won't be stereo anymore, but mono sound on both channels is better than an unbalanced stereo channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to make it mono. You can get the audio out of the file ([using one of these](http://www.blazemp.com/)), fix the volume from the sound, then combine the new audio part with the video again :)

Comment: What option to use to fix the volume?

Comment: My solution was to extract the mp3 out of the avi using Blaze Media. For some odd reason, the volumns in the mp3 is correct. I didn't know how to use Blaze Media to mux the video and audio (if it can do it) so I used another tool 'Total Video Converter' to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[FFDSHOW](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/FFDshow.htm) has several audio filters dealing with volumes. You reach them by right-clicking the audio icon in the tray when the video is playing. One of them is the equalizer.

See this article for more details:
[Simple FFDShow Audio Settings](http://www.hack7mc.com/2009/02/simple-ffdshow-audio-settings.html)

[image]

Comment: Is this tool used during playback? I need to convert a video file so that I can copy it to a portable player.

Comment: This is for playing. For converting there are tools like VirtualDub.